# thread scheduling in java with executor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, scheduling, threadpoolexecutor

**Where and What**

I've implemented a Java program which is composed of 3 tasks scheduled one by one:

1. the first task is really fast (basic process)
2. the second task is really slow (compound and linked processes)
3. the last task is really fast (basic process), must be done once a time (can't be used by more than one thread a time)

**What I have**

This program process thousand of data a hour, each data will pass by the 3 tasks.

**The question**

What is the best way to schedule all this stuff?

**What I tried**

1. *ThreadPoolExecutor* foe each task:  I got *GC overhead limit exceeded* minutes after the first run (but all the tasks runs well)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the order must be 1-2-3 and data elements are independant from each other, then can you put all in a single thread to eliminate thread switch time? Maybe realy fast means very few instructions in 1 and 3 so thread switch(and thread/core communication) could be taking more time than that ?

Comment: Can you show a bit of your code? More specifically - the part where you submit tasks.

Comment: to @huseyintugrulbuyukisik : if i make all the tasks in one thread , this can be huge don't you think ? the only reason for why i subdivised the work on 3 tasks is to (i wich) go fast with my program.

Comment: to @user1873880 : here you are how my code is implemented :

i use *ThreadPoolExecutor*

`ThreadPoolExecutor A,B,C;
(A | B | C) = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,100, Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(Integer.MAX_VALUE), threadFactory, rejectionHandler);`

PROGRAM :
`THREAD 1 IS CALLED IN A.
 THREAD 2 IS CALLED FROM THREAD 1 IN B.
 THREAD 3 IS CALLED FROM THREAD 2 IN C.`

Comment: no one to help !? iam swiming for a while